# R regex to get partly match

Tags: r, regex-greedy, stringi

I want to use stri_replace_all_regex to replace string but failed. I would like to know whether there are other methods to overcome it.
Thanks for anyone who gives help to me!

try:
the first:

```
> library(string)
> a <- c('abc2','xycd2','mnb345','tumb b~','lymavc') 
> b <- c('ab','abc','xyc','mnb','tum','mn','tumb','lym','lymav') 
> stri_replace_all_regex(a, "\\b" %s+% b %s+% "\\S+", b, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

However, the result is :

```
> c("ab","xyc","mn" ,"tum b~","lym")
```

which is not I want.
I want the result should be:

```
> c('abc','xyc','mnb','tumb','lymac')
```

the second:

```
> pattern <- paste0("\\b(", b, ")\\S+", collapse = "|")
> gsub(pattern, "\\w", a)
```

However it failed.
I feel sorry it's my mistake that I do not express clearly.
In fact, I want to replace `b` with `a`.
As you see, `a` and `b` have some similar parts on the left， I want to remove the difference from `a`. But should be greedy match.
For example:
The result of `'tumb b~‘` should be `'thumb'` not `'tum'` and the result of `'mnb345‘` should be `'mnb'` not `'mn'`.
I just learn regex expresion, so my try may be complex and cumbersome. Looking forward for your reply!

A new questions occurs.

> ```
> a <- c('tums310','tums310~20','tums320')  
> b<-c('tums1','tums2','tums3')
> ```

I want the result should be

> "tums3" "tums3" "tums3"

Comment: Could you explain in words what your rules are? Your pattern `"\\b" %s+% b %s+% "\\S+"` looks for a word starting with one of your `b` patterns and replaces it with the `b` pattern. It's certainly confusing to me when you have overlapping `b` patterns like `ab` and `abc` - maybe you want to rewrite them so the extensions are optional like `abc?` or maybe not. I'm not sure. It's also confusing that for the input `'tumb b~'` the expected output is `''tumb'` because the `\\S+` in your pattern is specifically **not** replacing spaces, but here you want to replace the space?

Comment: I feel sorry it's my mistake that I do not express clearly. In fact, I want to replace b with a. As you see, a and b have some similar parts on the left， I want to remove the difference from a. But should be greedy match. For example, the result of 'tumb b~‘ should be 'thumb' not 'tum' and the result of 'mnb345‘ should be 'mnb' not 'mn'.  I just learn regex expresion, so my try may be complex and cumbersome. Looking forward for your reply!

Comment: Should the last desired match be `lymac` or `lymav`?

Comment: o  yes an error occurs I would revise...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for `adist`.

```
a <- c('abc2','xycd2','mnb345','tumb b~','lymavc') 
b <- c('ab','abc','xyc','mnb','tum','mn','tumb','lym','lymav')
b[apply(adist(b, a) + adist(b, a, partial=TRUE), 2, which.min)]
#[1] "abc"   "xyc"   "mnb"   "tumb"  "lymav"

a <- c('tums310','tums310~20','tums320')  
b <- c('tums1','tums2','tums3')
b[apply(adist(b, a) + adist(b, a, partial=TRUE), 2, which.min)]
#[1] "tums3" "tums3" "tums3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. A new questions occurs. 
`a <- c('tums310','tums310~20','tums320') `
`b<-c('tums1','tums2','tums3') `
`b[apply(adist(b, a), 2, which.min)]`
the result is:
`[1] "tums1" "tums1" "tums2"`
however I want the result should be 
`"tums3" "tums3" "tums3"`

Comment: I updated using in addition `partial` to find the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will spend time in learning these. Good wishes for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `fuzzy_join` solution with the function `stringdist_join`:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_join(
  # join `b` as a dataframe ... 
  data.frame(b),
  # ... with `a` as a dataframe:
  data.frame(a),
  # join by ...:
  by = c("b" = "a")
  # use left join:
  mode = 'left',
  # use Jaro-Winkler distance metric:
  method = "jw",
  # enable case-insensitive matching:
  ignore_case = TRUE,
  # name for distance column:
  distance_col = 'dist') %>% 
# retain only closest matches:
group_by(a) %>%
  slice_min(order_by = dist, n = 1)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   a [5]
  b     a         dist
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 abc   abc2    0.0833
2 lymav lymavc  0.0556
3 mnb   mnb345  0.167 
4 tumb  tumb b~ 0.143 
5 xyc   xycd2   0.133
```

`b` contains now the most closely matching values for `a`.

Comment: Does the answer help you? if it does, consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Have edited the answer (it contained a mistake resulting from an earlier version of the code)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a try you. Good wishes for you!